# get_template_part works on one server/host, but not another

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

On my own server, this worked fine:

```
query_posts(array('post_type'=>'events', 'paged' => get_query_var('page'), 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_key' =>'details_date'));
get_template_part( 'event-loop', 'events' );
```

Go to launch, move it over to client's server, and it won't work. It breaks the page actually, and the sidebar and footer don't show up. No error whatsoever, just blank space. "View Source" confirms that all HTML ceases after the "get_template_part" call. The same is happening to my "News" page, which also uses "get_template_part". I even moved these files back over to my own server to confirm they worked there, and they do. When I remove the "get_template_part", my sidebar and footer suddenly appear.

Is there any kind of server configuration that might prevent get_template_part from functioning correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When using get_template_part(), the second parameter is optional. All you need is the filename of your template part file without the .php extension. You also must ensure that the template part file is in the root of your Wordpress Theme folder. In your case I'm assuming your filename is 'event-loop.php'.

Try:

```
get_template_part('event-loop');
```

Or:

```
get_template_part('event', 'loop');
```